# New badges based on the number of badges earned

Tags: discussion, badge-request

There are various ways and conditions to earn badges, but I have a few more ideas for new badges:

- For every 100 **bronze** badges, earn 1 extra **silver** badge.
- For every 100 **silver** badges, earn 1 extra **gold** badge.
- For every 100 **gold** badges, earn 1 extra **gold** badge.
- For 5 **bronze** badges earned within 1 day, earn 1 extra **bronze** badge.
- For 10 **bronze** badges earned within 1 day, earn 1 extra **silver** badge.
- For 50 **bronze** badges earned within 1 day, earn 1 extra **gold** badge.
- For 5 **silver** badges earned within 1 day, earn 1 extra **silver** badge.
- For 10 **silver** badges earned within 1 day, earn 1 extra **gold** badge.
- For 20 **gold** badges earned within 1 day, earn 1 extra **gold** badge.

This is just an idea. It depends on the moderators and the community to accept it or not.

Comment: What would these badges be called? Also, 100 badges? Only people like Skeet can get that many!

Comment: I'd say we have more than enough badge hunting going on already.

Comment: no limits of hunting for community sites

Comment: Why do you format random words as code? Are there any programming languages where precious metals and "moderators" are code words?

Comment: see `down votes`, if first one give positive answer then all give positive response same for negative , here 2nd condition works. this question is for discussion not force to implement.

Comment: @jubin Downvotes on meta are different, and are commonly used to express agreement or disagreement.

Comment: I downvoted because you abused code formatting for things that are not code. I suspect that I'm not the only one. The few people who downvoted for other reasons probably [disagreed with your proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Should we also give you a "bonus" upvote for every 10 upvotes you get? What if, instead of devaluing these things, we actually require you *earn* them?

Comment: I think it should be same-type mapping, i.e. 100 bronze badges = 1 extra bronze badge, 100 silver badges = 1 extra silver badge, etc.

Answer (score 11):

To what effect?

Let the badges speak for themselves. Badges are supposed to do this; what would be the additional effect of adding more badges for earning badges?

If someone has 100 silver badges, they've contributed an incredible amount to the site. If someone has 100 silver badges and one gold badge for earning those silver badges, my impression of them has not changed. Badges for earning badges are not meaningful because they don't say anything new about the user.

(Side note: 100 gold badges is a phenomenal record which has only been achieved by very few people. For those people, for instance, the difference between 100 and 101 badges is meaningless when put in the perspective of their other contributions.)

Comment: Jon Skeet has 202 gold badges haha.

Comment: why you stuck on one line?

Comment: @jubin The answer can be extended to all the other suggestions. Badges for earning badges are not meaningful because they don't say anything new about the person. (Editing this into the post.)

Comment: @jubin ...what does that mean?

Comment: @jubinPatel Just...What?

Comment: why? you think no one will get that? SO has no plan to close community :)

Answer (score 11):

It is not needed.

If a user can earn 100 bronze badges, then it will not be a big thing for that user to get one silver badge. At that time the user could gain more than 30 silver badges. Badges are given for various reasons in the community, but awarding badges to badge gaining is not a good idea like giving reputations for earning reputations(ie, earning 100 reputation will get 10 rep free). It won't add any value to the user.

Comment: this is just idea to give badges infront of others badges

Comment: @jubinPatel, as a new user, badges are more far to you to attain, at the view of a 100 bronze badge holder, it won't be a big thing to get one more silver badge.

Comment: i am not say to give 1 for 100 that will be your idea and you not give response for after first 3 suggestions(daily base)

Answer (score 5):

We already have people farming badges just for the badges. Why make it a pyramid scheme?

Badges are supposed to reward some specific merit worthy action. Going all meta on folks (making being worthy of merit an abstract merit) only adds a layer of separation between the behavior you are trying to encourage and the reward for it.